# Should i load each different version of jQuery or no?

Tags: jquery, performance

If i have many plugin on my web app, should i load each different version of jQuery or just the lastest CDN of jQuery?

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: it depends on what the other plugins are compatible with

Answer (score 0):

Use just latest version of jQuery

Answer (score 0):

You should load **the latest**.

Indeed, a plugin which has been written in jQuery **1.12.4** should work in jQuery **3.2.1**, or at least, can be adapted if some of the old jQuery used methods are decreated.

Answer (score 0):

No ! use only one version, preferred latest one ! 
No need to include same functions twice right ?....

Answer (score 0):

No (but you can do it).

What is your target? The answer depends from the browser you should support, i.e. from your visitors, or the platform target of your app. All the plugins you are using still should respect your target.

Regarding features and bug-fixes, of course there are always good reasons to use the newest version of each library, but IMHO you won't find in the newest version a *cant-live-without* feature which can't replicated/emulated also with the 1.12.

From the jQuery website:

> If you need to support older browsers like IE 6-8,
>   Opera 12.1x or Safari 5.1+, use jQuery 1.12.

See here for more info: [Usage share of web browsers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Usage_share_of_web_browsers)